# Interested in home will mold problem . Can mold be in carpeting? Howe do i remove

Tags: drywall, insulation, flooring, painting

Interested in purchasing a home that has been empty for several years. Has a little mold on upstairs walls able to take care of that. One room has ceiling repairs with mold. Can the  mold go up into installation and will I have to remove all and resinsulate ceiling. One room has paneling how can I check for mold? Will I also have to replace carpeting because of mold. How can you tell if carpeting had mold.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a DIY job. Mold can spread everywhere in a wood-framed house full of drywall. Call in the pros to estimate the source and extent of the infection. Simply killing the mold won't help if you don't find the moisture source that made it moldy in the first place.

PSA to the world: stop building houses out of wood and drywall. Sheesh, what awful materials.

Comment: Although I find drywall and wood to be good building materials, I fully agree that this needs a licensed professional. You may actually do more damage than good without special training. Mold is like many ex girlfriends. Even though you took care of seeing it everyday, it'll come back to make life miserable. It's just a matter of 'when' not 'if'.

Comment: Wood and drywall are inexpensive and easy to *build* with. They are neither easy nor inexpensive to *live* with. :)

Comment: I shed a tear, that is beautiful. I don't have any tattoos yet, but that might just be the first! Until I can afford to build a house from a single billet of CNC aluminum with teak treads/flooring, I guess I'll have to settle.

Comment: Forget the aluminum, just use masonry! Doesn't grow mold, doesn't burn, doesn't rot, termites can't eat it, teenagers can't punch through it...